# How to define generic response type over exitants API using typescript

Tags: typescript, api, inheritance, response

I'm having trouble trying to define an inheritance model in order to make a generic response from my API.

The point is all my responses are currently having a status and a status message plus the content  of the response at the same level into the object.

So the resp1 structure is easily defined as  ResponseBaseContentOf, but how about to define the resp2 response style using something like ResponseBaseInheritsOf? can you see the difference?

```
export type ResponseStatus = 'OK' | 'NOK'
export const ResponseStatus = {
    Ok: 'OK' as ResponseStatus,
    Nok: 'NOK' as ResponseStatus
}

export interface ResponseBase {
    status: ResponseStatus,
    message: string
}

export interface ResponseBaseContentOf<T> extends ResponseBase {
    content: T
}

export interface MyClass {
    property01: string
    property02: number
}

const resp1: ResponseBaseContentOf<MyClass> = {
    status: 'OK',
    message: 'response ok',
    content: {
        property01: '01',
        property02: 2,
    }
}


ResponseBaseInheritsOf<MyClass>

const resp2 = {
    status: 'OK',
    message: 'response ok',
    property01: '01',
    property02: 2
}
```

Comment: Please provide NOK response

Answer (score 1):

In order to type failure/succes behavior, I believe you should use algebraic data types.

You have two valid states: `Success` and `Failure`. (OK and NOK in your particular case)

Hence, I assuming, that your data in the response should have also two states.

```js
const enum Messages {
  Success = 'Success',
  Failure = 'Failure'
}

type Success = {
  status: Messages.Success,
  message: string
}

type Failure = {
  status: Messages.Failure,
  message: null
}

type MyResponse = Success | Failure;
```

Now, you have only two possible states.

As you might have noticed, you are unable to make smth like that:

```js
const response: MyResponse = {
  status: Messages.Success,
  message: null
} // error, message should be string


const response2: MyResponse = {
  status: Messages.Success,
  message: 'some message'
} // ok
```

All you need to do is make illegal state unrepresentable.

In order to do it - you can use TypeScript union - I believe it is the most common way to do it.

Since, You did not provide any information about data structure in case of Success, I'm unable to help you define your type in your particular case.

Please provide some difference between success and failure response - then I will update my answer.

FOr now, I hope it will help you

**UPDATE**:

I think you are looking for smth like that:

```js
export type ResponseStatus = 'OK' | 'NOK'
export const ResponseStatus = {
    Ok: 'OK' as ResponseStatus,
    Nok: 'NOK' as ResponseStatus
}

export interface ResponseBase {
    status: ResponseStatus,
    message: string
}

type ResponseBaseContentOf<T> = ResponseBase & T

export interface MyClass {
    property01: string
    property02: number
}

const resp1: ResponseBaseContentOf<MyClass> = {
    status: 'OK',
    message: 'response ok',
    property01: '01',
    property02: 2,
}
```

Bth, [here](https://catchts.com/api) you can find some alternative ways of typing api requests and [here](https://catchts.com/unions#algebraic_types) you can find more about unions

Comment: you are right! I've edited the explanation, the example shows the OK response   ... I think union is the right way too, but I didn't get the notation for that for write the specification for  ResponseBaseInheritsOf<T>, using generic or something, in order to representate the resp2

Comment: I made an update. Try to use intersection in order to get rid of `content` property

Comment: Intersections!  that is it!